# Mapping one interface to others

Tags: typescript

I need to map interfaces to each other. I want to enter keys from `UserMap` and expect returning types from `IUserIncludes`. Moreover, if second element or array in `UserMap` is not null, I need to replace mapped interface by this element. So I expect `ab` to be like this:

```
{
  c: { replacedIdC: number };
  d: { idD: number };
}
```

But I can't properly iterate through `K`, that's a problem. And I have `ab` like that:

```
{
  c: { replacedIdC: number };
  d: { replacedIdC: number };
}
```

Code:

```
interface IUserC {
  idC: number;
}
interface IUserD {
  idD: number;
}
interface IUserIncludes {
  c?: IUserC;
  d?: IUserD;
}

interface UserMap {
  a: ['c', { replacedIdC: number }];
  b: ['d', null];
}

type BuildScope<
  Map extends { [key in keyof Map]: [keyof Include, any | null] },
  Include,
  K extends keyof Map = never,
> = {
  [val in Map[K][0]]: Map[K][1] extends null ? NonNullable<Include[val]> : NonNullable<Map[K][1]>;
};

const ab: BuildScope<UserMap, IUserIncludes, 'a' | 'b'>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFUDO0DCyDeAUMssACY4BcyIArgLYBG0A3IQL6GiSyIobYoAEQLFSZIdTpNWHLuGjwkaLNFQgEAG1pkImUSQQB+agNxsSZEysFC2neTyUpVUALJwADgeRxqAbQByBECAGgJkKAhPTT4yVAopBmYoZHYAXQtkRgDAsjCaWk1NTLlCMABPTxQAIVpgTTIAZQQAe2qAHjEPbwgAD0gQMn18ZH8AawgK0hBkSYrWmGQe9ID5xbQNbV1wuBBpgB9C4vS00LF1LR0Ic5IAaWR+weG5qY2e5ABeGggAN2hzgA+L4+fy-OCaGbLLz+O7pfwABnSq2hnlh8IAjKcnhAhvo6MVkEZkAA5VogElFWKMTQQDqXbYQMEQ9LA6hkilUuA0uk9dH+LGA+xsQhtECYMC+HLIOoNZptTquHrhMxQBnXTDhQJwQLII6BRiBIWEIA)

If I change `UserMap` structure to simple `key: string`, I can properly iterate through `K`, but I want to have opportunity to replace mapped type.

[Playground with simple `UserMap`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFUDO0DCyDeAUMssACY4BcyIArgLYBG0A3IQL6GiSyIobYoAEQLFSZIdTpNWHLuGjwkaLNFQgEAG1pkImUSQQB+agNxsSZEysFC2neTyUpVUALJwADgeRxqAcgR-C2RGALJguUIwAE9PFAAhWmBNMgBlBAB7eIAeMQ9vCAAPSBAyfXxkAG0AawgY0hBkOpjMmGQCgF1qFra0DW1ddgAaMXUtHQhRkgBpZGLS8ub6voLkAF4aCAA3aFGAPg2fKu24TUaOryqZzu7kADlMkHvaTU04Rk0IHPHBiBOzp19vY2IQsiBMGBfGFkEkUuksrlXAVhjY1ANJphUf44P5kAAfZD+Rj+YGEIA)

So, I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to use complex tuple type in `UserMap`, and if so, how to iterate through it?
2. If I don't want to replace mapped interface, I need to write `null` as second element. Is it possible to omit it? Now it says `Source has 1 element(s) but target requires 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer to first question. I need to iterate through `K` keys and I can rename them as I want, using `as` added in [TypeScript 4.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)

```
type BuildScope<
  Map extends { [key in keyof Map]: [keyof Include, object] },
  Include,
  K extends keyof Map = never,
> = {
  [key in K as Map[key][0]]: Map[key][1]
};
```

For second question I understand that tuple is array with defined length, so I can't define tuple with 2 elements and use it with only one.